# Can't create incron job

Tags: cron, fedora-20

I am trying to create incron job, but no success.

When I type:

```
incrontab -l
```

I got:

```
no table for vujke
```

and when I type:

```
incrontab -e
```

I got:

```
editor finished with error: No such file or directory
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of

```
echo $EDITOR
```

was empty, so I did:

```
export EDITOR=vi
```

then

```
incrontab -e
```

work like a charm!